# read the values from a csv and replace placeholders into a template

Tags: java, csv

Tried to find a solution but nothing so far.

With Java, I am trying to do this:

1) open a csv file (with many values)
3) save these values
4) replace some placeholders into a template with these values.

I've found many solutions (like Freemarker) but they work if the number of the values is fixed. **I'm looking for something to work for n (n unknown number of values!) values**.

E.g. csv
1, 2, 3, ..., n

Template
[fist-value] [second-value] [third-value] [4th value if value exists in the csv and so on] [5th value if...] and so on.

Please give me just an idea to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem correctly but if you want to use an unlimited number of placeholders in a line try something like `{n}` where n can be any positive integer. Or make `n` a string, i.e. a name for that placeholder. Overall I find it hard to understand what you're actually after. Can you provide some more elaborate example of input and desired output?

Comment: E.g. CSV:
name, surname, salutation
E.g Template
[1] - [2] - [3] - [4] -- becomes name - surname - salutation - --

[4] not present since there is no a fourth value into the csv file.

Answer (score 1):

> Q. Please give me just an idea to do that.?

Read line by line then [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) it using comma

Answer (score 1):

An idea can be to use [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html) to read the CSV file, and for the template part, to avoid using static markers and use list iterations instead.

An example Freemarker template for generating an HTML list can be as follows:

```
<ul>
    <#list rows as row>
        <li>
          <#list row as column>
            ${column}<#sep>, </#sep>
          </#list>
        </li>
    </#list>
</ul>
```

And to read the CSV and apply the template:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
Template template = cfg.getTemplate("src/template.ftl");

List<Iterable<String>> rows = new ArrayList<Iterable<String>>();
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
data.put("rows", rows);

File csvData = new File("/path/to/csv");
CSVParser parser = CSVParser.parse(csvData, CSVFormat.RFC4180);
for (CSVRecord csvRecord : parser) {
    Iterator<String> columns = csvRecords.iterator();
    rows.add(columns);
}

Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
template.process(data, out);
out.flush();
```